# How to install my own self-made iOS app on my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, apple-developer-account

I've got iPhone 13 with IOS 16.7.1 and iMac with Xcode  14 installed.

Recently I've made my own application for personal use.

I wanted to install this app on my iPhone by pushing “play” button on the top left corner on Xcode.

**The problem is** that this way of installing application on my iPhone works only 5-7 days, and than I need to reinstall it again.

Maybe there is a way that I can install my application on my iPhone for a longer (more then 5-7 days) time? I need it for the private purposes only and I don't want to publish it on the App Store. Also I don't want to pay for an Apple Developer Program 99$/1year because my application is becoming unprofitable.

Is there is any ways of side-installing my application for a long time and without buying Apple Developer Program?

I've tried to search the web for some information. I've found the solution to install my app like a beta-test using “test flight” but for this method I need to buy Apple Developer Program so this method does NOT suitable to me.

Maybe there is any free methods?

Comment: There is no way without paying for a developer program

Comment: And what about Chinese applications for iOS when you install them from a web-site using your Safari on your iPhone? Something like "Pangu" оr "G0blin Online Cydia" and so on?

Comment: I have no experience with those sites. I guess you could try them at your own risk. I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Under the current rules, you cannot.

https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

> If you’re signing in to Xcode with an Apple ID that’s not affiliated with the Apple Developer Program, you'll be able to perform on-device testing for personal use (Xcode refers to this as a Personal Team). However, there are some limitations to this type of development workflow that require you to re-provision the app to your device periodically, such as:

> The number of App IDs that can be registered your account at one time is limited to 10 and each expires after 7 days.

> The number of test devices that can be registered to your account for each platform is limited to 3 and each expires after 7 days.

> Provisioning profiles will expire 7 days from issuance, which may require you to rebuild and re-install your app to your device after expiration.